# Affine connection with torsion using xAct

Tags: mathematical-optimization, differential-geometry

I'm working with xAct and I need to obtain the affinne connection with torsion. Without torsion it is easy:

```
$ << xAct`xCoba` 
$ coord = {x, y, z, t};
$ n=4;
$ metric = {{a[t], 0, 0, 0}, {0, a[t], 0, 0}, {0, 0, a[t], 0}, {0, 0,   0, -P[t]}};
$ inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];
$ affine = Simplify[Table[(1/2)*Sum[(inversemetric[[i, s]])*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}]];
listaffine :=  Table[If[UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]],0], {ToString[\[CapitalGamma][i, j, k]], affine[[i, j, k]]}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}] TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 2], TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

And the output is:

$\Gamma [1, 1, 4] = \frac{a'(t)}{2 a(t)}$

$\Gamma [1, 4, 1] = \frac{a'(t)}{2 a(t)}$

$\Gamma [2, 2, 4] = \frac{a'(t)}{2 a(t)}$

$\Gamma [2, 4, 2] = \frac{a'(t)}{2 a(t)}$

$\Gamma [3, 3, 4] = \frac{a'(t)}{2 a(t)}$

$\Gamma [3, 4, 3] = \frac{a'(t)}{2 a(t)}$

$\Gamma [4, 1, 1] = \frac{a'(t)}{2 P(t)}$

$\Gamma [4, 2, 2] = \frac{a'(t)}{2 P(t)}$

$\Gamma [4, 3, 3] = \frac{a'(t)}{2 P(t)}$

$\Gamma [4, 4, 4] = \frac{P'(t)}{2 P(t)}$

How do I can implement torsion terms like that:

$K_{ij}^{0} = - \frac{a^{2}}{P^{2}}h(t) \delta_{ij}$

$K_{j0}^{i} = - h(t) \delta_{ij}$

$K_{jk}^{i} = f(t) \varepsilon_{ijk}$

?

where: $a(t)$ and $P(t)$ are time dependent function from metric. $h(t)$ and $f(t)$ are time dependent function from torsion, not from the metric. The Contortion tensor, $K_{\mu \nu}^{\rho}$ is given by

$K_{\mu \nu}^{\rho}=- \left(S{_{\mu \nu}^{\rho}}+{S}{^{\rho}_{\mu \nu}}+{S}{^{\rho}_{\nu \mu}}\right)$

with ${S}{_{\sigma \mu}^{b}}+{S}{_{\mu \sigma}^{b}}=0$, and the nonvanishing components are ${S}{_{i 0}^{j}}=\frac{h(t)}{2}\delta_{ij}$, ${S}{_{jk}^{i}}=S{_{[jk}^{i]}}=\frac{f(t)}{3{\varepsilon}{_{jk}^{i}}}$.